# ASP.net session issue with localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-timeout

I have an issue with sessions. My web site is implementing a logged users console, which register a new user each time it logs in. If I try to open 2 pages within the same web explorer, it fails because the method first ask if the user is already connected for not registering it twice.

This method take as parameter the sessionID, which is provided by .net
My question is: In the same browser (or in the same computer, localhost), the sessionID it's always the same or when is it generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SessionID will be the same for the same browser.
On a different browser (or a different computer) you'll get a different SessionID.

Thats kinda how it is all over the internet, not just with asp.net, because of the way Cookies work.

For example you'll notice that you can't log into amazon or ebay using different accounts within the same browser.

Comment: Actually regarding google this is not true: http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=69570

Answer (score 3):

By default, new tabs or new windows in a browser will share the same process and therefore the same temporary session cookies for a domain.

To open a new session in IE, choose File > New Session.

Answer (score 1):

SessionId is same per browser. You can check it by logging in to yahoo, the first page will ask for the user name and password, if you open the second page it will directly take you to your email account.

Answer (score 1):

Depends of the browser being used and how it's being used, as stated already the session is shared across the same browser on modern browsers by default.  Older browsers such as IE before 8 used to share the session across windows by default as well unless the user opened a new instance of IE outside of the browsers interface (i.e. Start Menu/Shortcut).