# Session starts and ends on every request, same session ID each time

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-variables

### Anomaly

For every page request, SESSION_START fires, immediately followed by a SESSION_END. If a session cookie doesn't exist, one(new SessionId) is automatically created, and both events are fired. If a session cookie already exists, the same/old SessionId is used. Even though the session cookie exists, session variables are lost on every request.

### Description

I have a simple log-in page which stores the log-in session, and redirects to a landing page. On the landing page, I check if the session variable exists, and if it doesn't, redirect the user to the login page.

```
// login.aspx
if (credentials valid)
{
    Session["login"] = username;
    Response.Redirect("landingpage.aspx", false);
}

// landingpage.aspx
if (Session["login"] == null) // this will always be true
{
    Response.Redirect("login.aspx", false);
    return;
}
```

In Global.cs, I create a log entry on 4 events: APPLICATION_START, APPLICATION_END, SESSION_START, SESSION_END. This is the log result on every page request.

```
Application Start
Session Start [asd...(session id 1)...qwe]
Session End [asd...(session id 1)...qwe]
Application End
```

Sometimes the same session is started and ended twice in a single page request.

```
Application Start
Session Start [asd...(session id 1)...qwe]
Session End [asd...(session id 1)...qwe]
Session Start [asd...(session id 1)...qwe]
Session End [asd...(session id 1)...qwe]
Application End
```

After manually deleting the session cookie from the browser(Chrome), the next request will still create a session cookie and fire the events.

```
Application Start
Session Start [zxc...(session id 2)...rty]
Session End [zxc...(session id 2)...rty]
Application End
```

### Config / Failed solutions

- I've tried using .NET 4.0 and 4.5 framework.
- I'm using IIS7.
- Both cookieless states(true/false) produce the same result.
- System logs show no application pool restarts.
- I've set a dummy variable in SESSION_START event.

```
//web.config
<compilation targetFramework="4.0"/>
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30" cookieless="false"/>

//SESSION_START event
Session["SESSION_ALIVE"] = "SESSION_ALIVE";
```

I can feel my hair graying over this. Help my scalp, o' SO.

**Edit**
I have found the exact cause for this behavior.
 1. When the page is requested, `Application_Start` and `Session_Start` are fired.
 2. If anything is done in the App_Code folder(which includes *viewing* the files in visual studio), `Session_End` and `Application_End` are fired. My guess is this somehow restarts the application pool.

My question now is:
 1. Why does this happen?
 2. Why is my session ID always the same?
 3. The session cookie is never destroyed. Is this intended?
 4. Yes/No answer to 3: Why?

**Edit 2**
I have discovered the real true cause for this behavior(application stops abruptly).
There are several ways to replicate this. I'm using VS2012 if that matters.
 1. When an App_Code file's window receives focus in Visual Studio.
 2. When *any* file is saved in the project, even when no changes are made.
 3. When the VS preview window is opened. This happens when *any* code file is selected in the solution explorer.

This really bothers me and I know it shouldn't happen. I could just insert back the session validation after doing everything else but that only cures the symptoms not the problem. Also, I know this can probably be a new question, but I'm not sure if it even qualifies to be its own question so I'm putting it here(for now maybe?).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be doing it correctly. But, I'd like to know little bit more.

Do you have any of the following somewhere in your code?

Session.Abandon
Session.RemoveAll (or any remove methods)

Do you have any explicit session time out set instead of the default?

Do you have your application hosted in multiple servers? Load balancing etc.

If you post your Global.asax.cs code would be helpful.

**Alternatively, you may try to use following instead of** `Session[key] = val;`

```
HttpContext.Current.Session[key] = val;
```

Comment: I've tried adding Session.Abandon before creating a new "login" session variable to no effect. The only place session timeout is set is in the web.config file. No load balancing/web farms; it's a single thread application. The Global.cs file only logs the events with the exception of SESSION_START which adds a dummy variable into the session.

Comment: @ttj: Where did you use Session.Abandon? Because, we should only use it in Session_End or Application_End.

Comment: Right before `Session["login"] = username;`. It wasn't there initially; it's just one of the things I tried to solve the problem which happens regardless.

Comment: Ok, remove that. It'll not be helpful because the session is only queued to be deleted until all code is executed. More info @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524310(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Try following. Add Session["login"] = "Some string" in Application_Start or Session_Start and keep your current logic same (in your login and landing pages). Also recycle the application pool if hosted in IIS or close IIS Express if debugging locally and try again. Good luck!

Comment: 1. If you change a dependant file like web.config the application gets recycled and application_end will get fired.

2. Following links will help you in answering this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912126/asp-net-session-issue-with-localhost
http://forums.asp.net/t/1532145.aspx

3 & 4. Above links will answer these too

hope this helped.

Answer (score -3):

try adding this in your web.config

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="StateServer"></sessionState>
</system.web>
```